# How to make a transference layer on an image which reduces the image light at the corner but not at the center of the image

Tags: html, css

How to make a transference layer on an image which reduces the image light at the corner but not at the center of the image? I need the result exactly as shown below:

[image]

I have tried the below code:

```css
img {
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    filter: blur(5px);
    border-radius: 15px 50px 30px 5px;
    background: #73AD21;
    padding: 20px; 
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px; 
 
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>

<img src="http://zblogged.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/17.jpg" alt="Pineapple" width="300" height="300">

</body>
</html>
```

Please help to do the required change to get the required output.

Answer (score 2):

An absolutely positioned pseudo-element on a wrapping div and a sem-transparent box-shadow is one method.

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}
.wrap {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 1em;
}
.wrap::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
  top: 10%;
  left: 10%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 200px rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.35);
  z-index: 1;
}
img {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <img src="http://zblogged.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/17.jpg" alt="Pineapple" width="300" height="300">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

An absolutely positioned element in a wrapping div with a radial background is another method

```css
.img {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}
img {
  display: block;
}
.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: radial-gradient(circle, transparent 50%, rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5) 50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="img">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/eb/Ash_Tree_-_geograph.org.uk_-_590710.jpg" width="200">
  <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to wrap the image in a container and put an overlay div to can achieve the desired results

```css
.img {
   

    width: 250px;
    position:relative;
 
}
img{
max-width:100%;
}
.overlay{
  position: absolute;
  background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7); /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(circle,transparent 50%, rgba(0,0,255,0.7) 50%); /* Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<div class='img'>
  <div class='overlay'></div>
<img src="http://zblogged.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/17.jpg" alt="Pineapple" width="300" height="300">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```